# WinSCP transferring PDF from unix to window

Tags: java, unix, pdf, winscp

I am working on a project using Java that embedding PDF with text file. So far, I developed and tested on development tool Eclipse, the program run perfectly smooth and the result were as expected.

I try to run the program on unix, program was run, directories and files created as expected. I verified the result by transferring the PDF from unix to window by using winSCP, I try “Binary” and “Text” from Transfer Setting selection, it came out two different problems.

First of all, I clicked “Text” from the Transfer Setting selection, winSCP finished transfer. I opened the PDF and an error occurred, “Insufficient data for image”. I checked the embedded text file, it presented perfectly lines by lines.

Then, I chose “Binary” and winSCP transferred to window completely. I opened the PDF, it showed perfectly.  However, the sentences in the embedded text file massed together in one line.

Did I set something wrong or using wrong transfer method? Or something I looked over?

Thankyou in dvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `winscp` you could go for alternatives like ftp, sftp, setting a nfs share between your windows and unix machine or putting your pdf files inside a tar/zip/tar.gz file to transfer it to windows (in binary mode) to avoid any transfer problem.

> *Then, I chose “Binary” and winSCP transferred to window completely. I opened the PDF, it showed perfectly. However, the sentences in the
>   embedded text file massed together in one line.*

Regarding, this point do you now that the unix EOL symbols are not the same than in windows `\n` vs `\r\n`? This might explain why you have your text, massed together. You might have to change your java code to produce windows style `carriage return`,  or use `unix2dos/tr` tools.

Last but not least, you could also try to open your pdf directly on Linux to check the result.

Comment: Allan, after the weekend refreshing, i went back to my office and modified the java code as your instructions, it worked perfectly. Many thanks.